# How to type straight line as in [attribute?="value"]

Tags: html, css

In the title I added a question mark. It's supposed to b a straight line. How do u type it?

I've tried googling it but idk what it's called.

I believe this line has also been used to divide Home News About Contact

I really appreciate the help, Thank you

Comment: By `straight line`, do you mean a `|`?

Comment: Straight line vertically `attribute |=` or horizontally `attribute -=` ?

Comment: Can you cut-and-paste an actual example from your css source file?

Comment: On my keyboard, it is on the same key as the backslash, just above the `enter` key. Need to use shift to add it to the text.

Answer (score 2):

The glyph `|` is called the [vertical line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar), and is also known as a *(vertical) pipe* or *vertical bar* (U+007C). It can be typed on many keyboards using <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> (it will likely be printed on the corresponding key on your keyboard).

When used in a CSS selector in the form of `[attr|=value]`, it is [described on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#attrvalue_3) this way:

> Represents elements with an attribute name of *attr* whose value can be exactly *value* or can begin with *value* immediately followed by a hyphen, `-` (U+002D). It is often used for language subcode matches.

```css
[class|="size"] { color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="size">size</div>
<div class="size-small">small</div>
<div class="size_medium">medium</div>
<div class="size large">large</div>
<div class="size-small-or-large">small or large</div>
```